# Proving this is a theorem of S5 in modal logic

Tags: proof-verification, logic, proof-explanation, modal-logic

I need to prove the following is a theorem in $\mathbf{S5}$:

$$ \Diamond A \wedge \Diamond B \rightarrow (\Diamond (A \wedge \Diamond B) \vee \Diamond (B \wedge \Diamond A)). $$

I have the following axioms:
(i) $\Box A \rightarrow A$

(ii) $\Box A \rightarrow \Box \Box A$

(iii) $A \rightarrow \Box \Diamond A$

and the duals of these, and the standard axioms, theorems and rules of minimal modal logic.

I know there is also a theorem of S5, namely (iv) $\Diamond A \rightarrow \Box \Diamond A$.

**Attempt:**
I had so far: 1) $A \wedge B \rightarrow A \wedge \Diamond B$ by dual of (i).

Similarly 2) $A \wedge B \rightarrow \Diamond A \wedge B$

Hence 3) $A \wedge B \rightarrow (A \wedge \Diamond B) \vee ( \Diamond A \wedge B)$.

Then 4) $$ \Diamond \Diamond \Box (A \wedge B) \rightarrow \Diamond \Diamond \Box [ (A \wedge \Diamond B) \vee ( \Diamond A \wedge B)]$$ from 3) applying Becker rule.

But 5) $$ \Diamond \Diamond \Box [ (A \wedge \Diamond B) \vee ( \Diamond A \wedge B)] \rightarrow \Diamond [(A \wedge \Diamond B) \vee ( \Diamond A \wedge B)] $$ by dual of (iii).

Since $\Diamond \phi \vee \Diamond \psi \leftrightarrow \Diamond (\phi \vee \psi)$ is a standard rule, the consequence of 5) would imply the desired result. So it is sufficient to prove that $$ \Diamond A \wedge \Diamond B \rightarrow \Diamond \Diamond \Box (A \wedge B). $$ And this is the part where I am stuck.

Anyone has advice? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you also interested in a semantic proof?

Comment: I'd prefer axiomatic.

Comment: By semantic you mean? Showing that the negation leads to a contradiction with all the axioms?

Comment: I meant using Kripke models and the characterization of S5 for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good reason why you cannot prove the part where you're stuck: it is not anywhere close to valid. It is a good idea to learn semantics, even if you are required to work with formal systems, so you can easily recognize these things.

Something crucial about S5 is that once you put a modal operator on something, additional modal operators don't do anything. It's very quick to prove just from the axioms you wrote down that $\square\square A\leftrightarrow \square A$ and $\square\lozenge A\leftrightarrow\lozenge A.$

I'm not sure what the assigner of this exercise had in mind, but this theorem is way weaker than it needs to be. In fact, the premise is equivalent to both of the disjuncts in the conclusion (another thing semantics will allow you to see easily). So we can just prove $(\lozenge A\land\lozenge B)\to \lozenge(A\land \lozenge B),$ or in dual form, $\square (A\lor \square B)\to (\square A\lor \square B).$

Well, axiom K says $\square (p\lor q) \to (\lozenge p\lor \square q),$ so as an instance of this, $\square(A\lor \square B)\to (\square A\lor\lozenge \square B).$ But recall from what I said at the outset, that $\lozenge \square B\leftrightarrow \square B,$ so we're done.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. We learned axiom K as saying $\Box (A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow (\Box A \rightarrow \Box B). $ Is that equivalent to your version? Could you show the equivalence? Also, I do not understand your substitution instance. If I set $p = A$ and $q = \Box B$, I get $\Box (A \vee \Box B) \rightarrow (\Diamond A \vee \Box \Box B)$.

Comment: Yes. $A\to B$ is equivalent to $\lnot A\lor B,$ so we have $\square(\lnot A\lor B) \to (\lozenge(\lnot A)\lor \square B)$.  Try $p=\square B$ and $q=A$ instead.